# SVG rendering smaller in mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, mobile-safari

I am creating a custom SVG button, but I cannot figure out why in mobile Safari my icon is rendering much smaller than all of the other browsers.

**HTML**

```
<button>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M22 5.72l-4.6-3.86-1.29 1.53 4.6 3.86L22 5.72zM7.88 3.39L6.6 1.86 2 5.71l1.29 1.53 4.59-3.85zM12.5 8H11v6l4.75 2.85.75-1.23-4-2.37V8zM12 4c-4.97 0-9 4.03-9 9s4.02 9 9 9c4.97 0 9-4.03 9-9s-4.03-9-9-9zm0 16c-3.87 0-7-3.13-7-7s3.13-7 7-7 7 3.13 7 7-3.13 7-7 7z"/>
  </svg>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
  /* Button Reset */
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  background: transparent;
  /* inherit font & color from ancestor */
  font: inherit;
  /* Corrects font smoothing for webkit */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  fill: #5f6368;
}
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/plumbblake/pen/yLyjbeR)

**Goal**: Make icon the same size across major browsers.

Comment: Remove the height of the svg element from the css. Alternatively try using `box-sizing: content-box; padding:0` for the button. In this moment you are forcing the size of the svg element. To understand what happens add an outline for the svg

Comment: The problem was not resetting the padding to 0 in Safari! Thank you!

Comment: @BlakePlumb Make an answer with your comment on padding. It is the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here was that my "Button Reset" was not complete.  I needed to set a padding of 0 to the button.